# Why does the post-hoc results in R differs the post-hoc results in SPSS?

Tags: r, spss, post-hoc

I have run the same two-way Repeated Measure ANOVA in R and in SPSS. Following that I ran a Fisher's Least Significant Difference (LSD).

**R script**

```
#The main ANOVA
library(ezANOVA)
anova <- ezANOVA(data = Data, 
                  dv = .(Var),
                  wid = .(Subject), 
                  within = .(Days), 
                  between = .(Group), 
                  detailed = FALSE, 
                  type = 3);
#The post-hoc
attach(Data)
LSD <- pairwise.t.test(Var, Group, p.adj="none")
```

For SPSS, I used the General Linear Model then Repeated Measure and compared the main effects using the LSD option.

**Results**:
The results of the two-way Repeated measure ANOVA is exactly the same for R and SPSS. However, the post-hoc p-value slightly differ.

**Questions:** What causes this difference? Does it have to do with how SPSS runs the LSD test. Which LSD test is most reliable?

Comment: Where is the data (some example)? Where is the SPSS syntax? Come and show it. How can somebody check your results?

Comment: I guess their algorithm of LSD test are equivalent. But they use different statistics. SPSS uses estimated marginal means (adjusted for the covariates; [manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_22.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/spss/advanced/idh_glmr_opt.htm)). R uses observed means. I think both are reliable but different things.